# How to wire tap inside a filter in camel

Tags: apache-camel

I am new to camel and i have to wire tap a filter inside a route of a given camel application. The application only uses xml-flavor. Because i could add `<wireTap>` inside any tag (i get no error) i guess it should be possible?!
Here is the route with wire tap:

```
<route id="cep-output-postpaid" autoStartup="true">
        <from
            uri="someUri" />
        <log message="Output: ${body}" />
        <to
            uri="file:someFile?fileName=result.csv&amp;fileExist=Append"></to>
        <filter>
            <method ref="filterAfterDownTime" method="numberOfDaysToFilter(${body}, 100)" />
            <process ref="processor1"></process>
            <throttle timePeriodMillis="10000">
                <constant>40</constant>
                <wireTap uri="direct:wireTap"/>
                <to uri="someWsdlService"></to>
            </throttle>
            <process ref="processor1"></process>
        </filter>

        <log message="Done CEP Engine Output" />
    </route>
```

The bean is referenced like this:

```
<bean id="wireTap" class="somePackage.WireTap"></bean>
```

And finally the wire tap class:

```
public class WireTap {

    public PcrfEdrPostpaidWireTap(){
        System.out.println("wiretap constructor called");
    }

    @Handler
    public void handleBody(String body){
        System.out.println("Wiretap says:" + body);
    }
}
```

The problem is neither the constructor nor the method is called but the rout is running and produces its output.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**Additional Questions:** 
How to use "seda" here? (i want to decouple the wiretap from the processing)
and
Is it possible to give the wiretap a parameter (e.g. path to a file for the wire tap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah you should use the bean component if you want to call a method on a bean
http://camel.apache.org/bean

So change

```
<wireTap uri="direct:wireTap"/>
```

To

```
<wireTap uri="bean:wireTap"/>
```

And mind you can give the bean any id you want, you dont have to call it wireTap.

Comment: Thx this was fast.
in some examples i saw "seda" (i think this decouples the wirtap), how  to wiretap with this uri="seda:bean:wireTap"?

Comment: You cannot use both seda and bean component in the same uri. A seda usually is used has handoff between routes, so you route to a seda queue, and then another route continues that message.