# How to give a wire tap bean an additional parameter

Tags: apache-camel

Thx to Claus i got a [wire tap working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22917941/how-to-wire-tap-inside-a-filter-in-camel/22918087) using a bean. But is there a way to give it a parameter (probably via header?)?
In my case i would like to specify a file for output.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass headers as parameters into your bean method, so for example if you have a header called "fileName":

```
public class WireTap {

    public PcrfEdrPostpaidWireTap(){
        System.out.println("wiretap constructor called");
    }

    @Handler
    public void handleBody(String body, @Header("fileName") String fileName){

        System.out.println("Wiretap says:" + body + " and the fileName is: "+fileName);
    }
}
```

More info can be found here: https://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html and here http://camel.apache.org/parameter-binding-annotations.html

**EDIT:** To set a header you can use this:

```
<setHeader headerName="fileName">
    <constant>SampleFileName.txt</constant>
</setHeader>
```

You would do this before performing the wireTap

Comment: yeah use bean parameter binding. And also read from here about more bean stuff in Camel: http://camel.apache.org/bean-integration.html

Answer (score 0):

Use camel [annotations](http://camel.apache.org/parameter-binding-annotations.html) to inject parameter values while doing bean invocation